# Can I output Elixir terms with colour?

Tags: elixir

In `iex`, terms are coloured nicely. Can I take advantage of this in my own programs? Is there something like `IO.color_inspect`?

Comment: Assuming you're not using Windows.  Windows doesn't support any of this stuff :(

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci not necessarily true... colours work just fine on windows with ConEmu terminal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `IO.inspect` and `inspect` allow you to pass `syntax_colors` option where you can specify the color you want for each type of term as documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html). Unfortunately, it looks like the configuration used by IEx is not exposed so you'll have to copy paste or make your own.

```
iex(1)> syntax_colors = [number: :yellow, atom: :cyan, string: :green, boolean: :magenta, nil: :magenta]
[number: :yellow, atom: :cyan, string: :green, boolean: :magenta, nil: :magenta]
iex(2)> IO.inspect [1, :a, "b", nil], syntax_colors: syntax_colors; :ok
[1, :a, "b", nil]
:ok
```

[image: iex]

Comment: Since Elixir 1.14, you can use `IO.ANSI.syntax_colors/0` to obtain the default configuration.

Answer (score 6):

See the [`IO.ANSI`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.ANSI) library for rendering ANSI escape sequences to control formatting, colour, etc.

[ExUnit's CLI formatter has some good usage examples](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/8e73f5e03d2b7f3cdd26f730c2c9b4965e459b57/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/cli_formatter.ex#L307-L361).

Using it can be as simple as concatenating or interpolating ANSI characters for foreground or background colours and resets. For example

[image: IO.ANSI example using foreground colours]